# Change boot device order by default to windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

Long back I dual booted my system, installed ubuntu alongside windows. But while removing the same instead of safe removing the OS I deleted the partition in which I had Ubuntu.

Now since then whenever my computer starts it loads the ubuntu grub loader program

[image]

I need to manually change the boot option to windows every time I start my computer.

[image]

I tried changing the default to windows, but I don't know why its resetting the option to Ubuntu every time.

[image]

How do I make windows the default option also is there any way to delete this ubuntu grub loader?

Comment: On the Boot Option Menu you have pressed enter to change the order?  The reason the UEFI boot order is reverting is likely due to the boot option setting.  You could try editing BCD but without experience in doing so you risk doing something incorrectly and it's not easily explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, open Command Prompt as an Administrator. Run this

```
bcdedit /enum firmware
```

Make note of the `identifer` value for the entry with a `path` value of `/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi (or grubx64.efi)` and a `description` value of `ubuntu`.

Delete that boot entry:

```
bcdedit /delete {identifier-for-ubuntu-goes-here}
```

For further cleanup, delete Grub files: (this is optional)

```
mountvol S: /s
rd S:\EFI\ubuntu /s /q
```

Reboot to test it.

Source : [u/funbike](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/pfcw2b/change_boot_device_order_by_default_to_windows/hb3x1qz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)